# Regex to match spaces and tabs between words

Tags: regex

There is `<tab> <space> <tab>` between words.

```
Reskontradatum      Transaktionsdatum       Text        Belopp      Saldo
2012-10-01      2012-09-30      SATS-TIGER AIR      -92,17      629,07
2012-10-01      2012-10-01      Per oktober         -1 000,00       721,24
2012-09-30      2012-10-02      ÖVERTRASSRÄNTA      -1,00       1 721,24
```

How can I remove them (without removing spaces in words like `SATS-TIGER AIR`)?

Comment: Why don't you just look it up?

Comment: In which language? What do you mean with "special character"? What should the result look like? What have you tried? Your "question" is so unclear!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but it looks like you want to remove all the tabs and spaces *when there are both tabs and spaces between words* - i.e not when there are only space characters or only tab characters between words.

This regex looks for one or more spaces and one or more tabs between two words:

```
\b(\s+\t+)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are asking, but the regular expression for matching a tab is \t.  If there is maybe more than one you could match it with \t+

Also, it would depend what language you are using to implement your regular expressions

Comment: We need a regular expression  to  remove tabs and spaces in between them. for example ,
2012-10-01<tab><space><tab>2012-09-30
and it should not affect the spaces for phrases like "SATS-TIGER AIR"